# make: $LD_RUN_PATH is ignored

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg, makefile, ld

I'm compiling FFmpeg from source.

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264
make
make install
```

`ldd /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` gave me this

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7717000)
libavdevice.so.53 => not found
libavfilter.so.2 => not found
libavformat.so.54 => not found
libavcodec.so.54 => not found
libpostproc.so.52 => not found
libswresample.so.0 => not found
libswscale.so.2 => not found
libavutil.so.51 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/tls/i686/nosegneg/libm.so.6 (0xb76e3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/tls/i686/nosegneg/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76ca000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/tls/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6 (0xb7569000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7718000)
```

Setting `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib` corrected the "not found" errors, but for the reasons mentioned [here](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html), I don't want to set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` permanantly.

I recomiled with the same commands, this time with `$LD_RUN_PATH` set to `/usr/local/lib`.
`make` seem to have ignored `$LD_RUN_PATH` when compiling.

Is there a way to use `$LD_RUN_PATH` without making extensive changes to the Makefile?

Comment: Can you link successfully by hand (i.e. on the command line, without using make)?

Comment: I don't know.  How can I test that?

Comment: Could you show us the part of the makefile that executes `ldd /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`?

Comment: How did you configure FFmpeg (i.e., what options did you pass to the ./configure script)? How did you install FFmpeg after building; did you manually copy 'ffmpeg' over to /usr/local/lib? Or did you perform 'make install'?

Comment: Check out http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux for the variables `LD_DEBUG` and `LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a reason to be compiling the binary in shared mode (like wanting to build software to link against them)? If a static 'ffmpeg' binary will work just as well for you, configure without the --enable-shared option to eliminate these dependencies.

Otherwise, you will need to let your system know where the shared libraries live, either by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the environment, prefixing executions of 'ffmpeg' with LD_LIBRARY_PATH (e.g., "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"), or update your system's library path with the right location.

There is one more solution that is at the very bottom of the page you linked in your post: "LDFLAGS='-L/my/strange/path/lib -Wl,-rpath /my/strange/path/lib'". For FFmpeg, and for your situation, pass this extra parameter at configure time:

```
--extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
```

And the resulting 'ffmpeg' binary will know where to find the shared libraries.

Many solutions to this one.

Comment: I don't know if I need the shared option, but that what the instructions use.  The `--extra-ldflags` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

1. Most probably LD_RUN_PATH is ignored because package's ./configure has already put some -Wl,-rpath options in linker's cmdline (frankly I don't know myself. I see the same behaviour here but I'm cross compiling from 486 to mips32).
2. try running configure like this:
   ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/your/lib -Wl,-rpath-link=/your/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/your/include" --prefix=/tgt ...

   I recommend using -rpath-link instead of -rpath if /your directory is different from /tgt

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who stumbles across this, the reason `$LD_RUN_PATH` wasn't working may have been due to [this bug](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13764) with the gold linker.

(The workaround is to use rpath as described in Mike's answer)